Power bi report not visible on site page
I created a site page for power bi report, but the report is only visible to me no other users can view that report. There is an error showing on that page:
"Upgrade the current Power BI license to view the report."
I have pro license, but other users don't have. Is it necessary to everyone have pro license to view that report or is there any other options for showing the report to everyone without having pro license?

Is there any progress on this thread? Please feel free to let me know.

I used the 'Publish to web (public)' option to make my dashboard visible to all users. I then embedded this report using the Site Pages embed option so that every user can view the report. However, when I tried the 'SharePoint Online' option and granted permissions to users, it displayed the error "Upgrade the current Power BI license to view the report." I am new to Power BI. Is my approach correct, or are there other options for achieving this?

Your licence is not used to publish your powerbi
Your WorkSpace should have a licence to publish
